# Unable to pass an array from parent LWC to child LWC setter method

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript-controller, array, setter, parent-to-child

Trying to pass a array value from parent component to child component using setter method in child LWC but empty value is being passed to child setter method. I am Using parent LWC as a quick action. any idea on why there is an issue passing array?

Note: Instead of array, if I pass a string value, there is no issue.

### Parent HTML

```
    <c-child record-id={caseId}
    loaded={loaded}
    scope-values={scopeValues}>
```

### Parent LWC.js

```
scopeValues = [];

 @api invoke()
    {        
        this.refreshInitialScopeDetails();             
    }
 refreshInitialScopeDetails() {
        this.scopeValues.push(this.orgId);  //getting orgId using lighting UI API

    }
```

### Child LWC.js

```
_initialScopeValues;

@api
  get scopeValues() {
    return this._initialScopeValues;
  }

  set scopeValues(value) {
      console.log('scope value '+value);
    if (value && value.length > 0) {
      this._initialScopeValues = value.join(",");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sudhir, please use the tools in the editor to format your code. I corrected it but your recent edit wiped out my changes.

Comment: Have you tried adding `@track` to scope `scopeValues` in parent? Otherwise the changes would not be observed. Also when is the invoke method called? After the wire returns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An inner mutation like calling `push()` on an array doesn't trigger the framework to rerender or fire setters. The framework is observing changes to the `scopeValues` property in the parent, but not to changes *within* that object.

One way to handle this is to make sure you do an assignment to the component-level property, so that you notify the framework of the change automatically:

```javascript
refreshInitialScopeDetails() { 
    this.scopeValues = [this.orgId, ...this.scopeValues];
    //getting orgId using lighting UI API
}
```

(This assumes you don't mind requiring ES9 support in your browser; otherwise you can use a construction with `Array.concat()`, or some other approach).

Answer (score 3):

There is still one use case for `@track`. When a field contains an object or an array, there's a limit to the depth of changes that are tracked. To tell the framework to observe changes to the properties of an object or to the elements of an array, decorate the field with `@track`.

Without using `@track`, the framework observes changes that assign a new value to a field. If the new value is not === to the previous value, the component rerenders.

You need to use `scopeValues = [];` in your parent LWC with `@track`

```
@track scopeValues = [];
```

Read more about `@track` reactive property in LWC [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_lwc_track.htm)